# Matlab conditional requirements with inputparser

Tags: matlab, function, input

I'd like to make a parameter in `inputParser` required if certain conditions are not met by the other arguments.  One way I can do this now is to write a subparser that checks the input and handles this.  Example:

```
function foo = subparser(bar, varargin)
p = inputParser; %initialize master parser
addRequired(p, 'bar', @(x) isscalar(x))
addParameter(p, 'conditional', 1, @(x) isscalar(x) || (iscell(x) && ~isempty(x)) 
addParameter(p, 'requireMe', [], @(x) isscalar(x))
parse(p,bar,varargin{:})

if isempty(p.Results.requireMe) % conditional requirement not supplied
    if iscell(p.Results.conditional) % we can get a default from the parameters supplied
        p.Results.requireMe = size(p.Results.conditional{1}, 1)
    else % argument is required
        error("'requireMe' is required when using default or scalar 'conditional'")
    end
end
foo = p.Results
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to handle this, perhaps using the built in abilities of inputParser?

Comment: I can't figure out any. Parameters are validated as stand-alone elements by the inputParser, and I think your code is good as it is currently. One suggestion: use a persistent inputParser.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo you mean passing an instance of `inputParser` around between functions or defining a global instance of `inputParser`?

Comment: Nope... see the persistent keyword in the documentation. You define the instance it within the function itself only once checking it with isempty.